# Is there a way to use old Print composer templates in 2.0?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, template

As the title says, the old templates do not work in 2.0.  It started with having to redraw boxes, now it causes it to crash completely.

Is there an easy fix.

Can i download templates for use??

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version 2.4? Unfortunately, I have neither an old project nor 2.0 to test ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which QGIS version are you using? 2.4 included some improvements to opening old templates, including a fix for the missing item borders. If you're using 2.4 or above, can you please file a bug at http://hub.qgis.org and attach a sample which crashes?

Comment: Running 2.0.1 from 1.8. Will download 2.4.  It never actually gives a log. It just stops responding then crashes. oh and when it did work, the boxes were blackened out.